# An entire function of irrational order

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

It's easy to construct an entire function of order $\frac{p}{q}$ for any positive integers $p,q$. But is there an example of an entire function of irrational order ($\sqrt2$ for example)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function#Order_.CF.81

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)=\prod _{i=1}^{\infty }x^{10^{-i}}$$

You can always generate things , till you have $\infty$ in your hand  :-)